# Warnings not displaying line numbers or jump to line option

Tags: swagger

I'm in the process of cleaning up this Swagger documentation file and I am unable to view the line flags for my warnings.

This is what is currently displayed:

⚠ Swagger Warning

Extra JSON Reference properties will be ignored: type, description

Details
Object code:  "EXTRA_REFERENCE_PROPERTIES"

message:  "Extra JSON Reference properties will be ignored: type, description"

path: Array [4]

level: 500

type:  "Swagger Warning"

description:  "Extra JSON Reference properties will be ignored: type,

description"

lineNumber: -1

I'm getting the usual warning flags without the line numbers or ability to jump to them. The gutter doesn't display the flags either. Did I somehow deactivate this feature or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using http://editor.swagger.io? Can you post your spec?

Comment: +Helen I'm using editor2.swagger.io. I don't think I'm allowed to post my spec because I don't want to be in violation of any of the work place rules. I was hoping I somehow hit a shortcut that disabled the features. Everything displays fine and while I'm not getting errors, I am getting warnings which I'm currently tasked with cleaning up. However, this issue only persists with this specific project and I've retained these features if I import another project.